# Vtiger 6.5 create ticket email not send any idea to fix it

Tags: php, email, sendmail, vtiger, vtigercrm

**Email not Send**

Email not when *ticket* add , update and assigned user

Answer (score 0):

You should check below things:

- IMAP installed on server or not?
- Outgoing server is configured correctly or not?
- If email notification is working then check the workflow of notification while new ticket.